# Indesign Script UI: Dynamic Add Text Edit Fields before OK-Cancel Buttons

Tags: dynamic, adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

I'm trying to show a script ui window that will add another group of input fields IF the user clicks an Add Another button instead of the OK or Cancel buttons...

I got it to kind of work... ie I can show a simple, two group, ui window
(group 1 = 1 text edit field and one dropdown list and the Add Another button
group 2 = normal OK-Cancel buttons)

If the user fills in/chooses in the first 2 input fields and then ignores the Add Another button and uses the OK-Cancel buttons the script proceeds fine.
BUT if the user clicks the Add Another button, the script utilizes a call-back/event handler function (add_AnotherInputline) to first remove the OK-Cancel button group and then add (through add_inputFields function) another group of the text edit field & dropdown, and then re-adds the OK-Cancel buttons... **(I could not figure out another way to get the OK-Cancel buttons to move or always stay at the bottom of the window!)**
BUT that removing-adding of the OK-Cancel button group is where my problem is surfacing. When I do that, those buttons no longer work after user utilizes the add_AnotherInputLine function... And this is seen in the Data Browser because at this point in the script the *cancelElement* and *defaultElement* now equal = *Object is invalid*

Here is the window/ui code... I hope this is enough. I've left out numerous priors (arrays, variables) used in the following code... if you need them, they're simple arrays with text items or ask and I can provide the variables/arrays containing content.

(And yes, I have the G. Singelmann script and have studied it extensively... I have yet to figure out a solution from it, for my particular need...)

```js
var myCSdialog = new Window("dialog", "Setup Color Coding");
    dialogSetup();
    //begin building dialog box myDialog
    add_inputFields(myCSdialog);
    
    if (myCSdialog.children.length <= 1) {
        normalButtons(myCSdialog);
    };
    
if (myCSdialog.show() == 1) {
        userCancelled = false;

} else {
    exit();
}; 

//function adds criteria input collection fields (text criteria and swatch choice)

function add_inputFields(myCSdialog) {
        var myEnterCriteriaGroup = myCSdialog.add("group");
        //title for first input
        myEnterCriteriaGroup.add("statictext",undefined,"Criteria to Color Code");
        //text entry field to enter criteria term
        var myEnterCriteria = myEnterCriteriaGroup.add("edittext",undefined,"");//field for entering text criteria
            myEnterCriteria.characters = 25;
            myEnterCriteria.active = true;
                           
        var myListOfColors = myEnterCriteriaGroup.add("dropdownlist",undefined,mySwatchNames);//dropdown field for choosing swatch
                            
        //add button to add another row of fields to gather another set of user input
        var addAnother_button = myEnterCriteriaGroup.add("button", undefined, "Add Another");
        
        //event handler registered
        addAnother_button.onClick = add_AnotherInputLine; //no passing parameters here! won't show button to be clicked!

            //event handler...callback functions put input into arrays
                myEnterCriteria.onChange = function() {
                    criteriaKeys.push(myEnterCriteria.text);
                };

                myListOfColors.onChange = function() {
                    if(myListOfColors.selection === null) {
                        myListOfColors.selection=myListOfColors.prevSel;
                    } else {
                        myListOfColors.prevSel=myListOfColors.selection.index
                    criteriaValues.push(myListOfColors.selection.text);
                    };
                };
      //if you don't add another group (add_AnotherInputLine() function...text edit field & dropdown) it hangs here... Ok or Cancel button do nothing...

};


 //function adds another input row (text criteria and swatch choice) need to find a way NOT to remove OK/Cancel buttons...
function add_AnotherInputLine() {
    myCSdialog.remove(myCSdialog.children[myCSdialog.children.length - 1]);
    add_inputFields(myCSdialog);
    
    if (myCSdialog.children.length >= 1) {
    normalButtons(myCSdialog);
    };
    
    myCSdialog.layout.layout(true);  
   };

//function adds OK - Cancel buttons
function normalButtons(myCSdialog) {
        var myDialogButtons = myCSdialog.add("group");
        myDialogButtons.alignment = "right";   
        myDialogButtons.add("button", undefined, "OK");
        myDialogButtons.add("button", undefined, "Cancel");
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I added comments below the lines that I added, to make it more understanable. I deleted some unnecessary lines as you can see.

```js
var mySwatchNames = app.activeDocument.swatches.everyItem().name

var myCSdialog = new Window("dialog", "Setup Color Coding");
    // dialogSetup();
    //begin building dialog box myDialog


    var maingroup = myCSdialog.add('panel')//Added line
    // You need to put those InputFields into a container, to make sure 
whenever you click on 'Add Another' button, the new fields will always 
above the Yes/No button

    add_inputFields(maingroup);
    //So whenever you generate new fields, it will be always inside its 
container 'maingroup', 
    //and the maingroup is the same level as YES/NO group, so YES/NO 
will be always at the very end of the dialog.

    normalButtons(myCSdialog);

    myCSdialog.layout.layout(true)//Added line
    // Why I put this line here? Because when the script renders the add_inputFields(maingroup) 
    //in the first time, there is another myCSdialog.layout.layout(true) at the end of the function dd_inputFields(maingroup).
    // After this function, if you create OK/Cancel buttons, they won't show up, because the line myCSdialog.layout.layout(true) stop u generating those buttons.
    // You need this line to re-render the dialog, to have OK/Cancel showed up.

    myCSdialog.show()
//function adds criteria input collection fields (text criteria and swatch choice)

function add_inputFields(maingroup) {
        var myEnterCriteriaGroup = maingroup.add("group");
        //title for first input
        myEnterCriteriaGroup.add("statictext",undefined,"Criteria to Color Code");
        //text entry field to enter criteria term
        var myEnterCriteria = myEnterCriteriaGroup.add("edittext",undefined,"");//field for entering text criteria
            myEnterCriteria.characters = 25;
            myEnterCriteria.active = true;
                           
        var myListOfColors = myEnterCriteriaGroup.add("dropdownlist",undefined,mySwatchNames);//dropdown field for choosing swatch
                            
        //add button to add another row of fields to gather another set of user input
        var addAnother_button = myEnterCriteriaGroup.add("button", undefined, "Add Another");
        
        //event handler registered
        addAnother_button.onClick = add_AnotherInputLine; //no passing parameters here! won't show button to be clicked!

            //event handler...callback functions put input into arrays
                myEnterCriteria.onChange = function() {
                    criteriaKeys.push(myEnterCriteria.text);
                };

                myListOfColors.onChange = function() {
                    if(myListOfColors.selection === null) {
                        myListOfColors.selection=myListOfColors.prevSel;
                    } else {
                        myListOfColors.prevSel=myListOfColors.selection.index
                    criteriaValues.push(myListOfColors.selection.text);
                    };
                };
                myCSdialog.layout.layout(true)//Added line
                //As I explained above, this line is just like you are asking the window to re-render the dialog, whenever you click 'Add Another' button.
                //This line will stop you generate the OK/Cancel buttons, so the dialog won't render them. That is why I added extra line at the top.

      //if you don't add another group (add_AnotherInputLine() function...text edit field & dropdown) it hangs here... Ok or Cancel button do nothing...

};


 //function adds another input row (text criteria and swatch choice) need to find a way NOT to remove OK/Cancel buttons...
function add_AnotherInputLine() {
    add_inputFields(maingroup);
    
   };

//function adds OK - Cancel buttons
function normalButtons(myCSdialog) {
        var myDialogButtons = myCSdialog.add("group");
        myDialogButtons.alignment = "right";   
        myDialogButtons.add("button", undefined, "OK");
        myDialogButtons.add("button", undefined, "Cancel");
};
```

Comment: TonyTan I think that will work! I understand if you don't have the time, but could you explain a little how your changes work but my original did not? I'm still quite new at this and would like to understand the logic behind something that works... 

for ex you added the w.layout.layout(true); in more places than I did. Why?
and you added the var maingroup and added that to the w as a panel and then passed that (maingroup) to various functions. Why? (one of my biggest struggles is understanding functions and passing things to/out of them)
Simple as possible answers will help. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer with comments to what I changed in your script. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much Tony! That does help.